# Captcha returns error message in laravel validator

Tags: php, validation, laravel, captcha

1. Using "mews/captcha": "dev-master-l4",
2. I controlled with dd() if i am able to get the values from the page, i can.
3. Problem : Captcha doesn't accept my input, 
   a. says it is empty when i enter correctly.
   b. says it is wrong when i enter wrong.

> ```
> <?php
> $myvalidator = Validator::make(
>             array(
>                 'anInput' => Input::get('input'),
>                 'passInput' => Input::get('pass'),
>                 'captchaInput' => Input::get('captchaInput')
>             ),
>             array(
>                 'anInput' => 'required|exists:myTable,myField',
>                 'passInput' => 'required',
>                 'captchaInput' => 'required|captcha',
>             )
>         );
> ?>
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem and i found the solution...when once you use captcha for example for login if you use captcha in another page session variable 'captcha' not clear and validation failed therefor i use

```
\Session::forget('captcha');
```

before load page that i used captcha in it.